# Move a virtualenv to another PC with different python edition

Tags: python, containers, virtualenv

I have two computers running the same OS with the same login credentials; let's call them `PC1` and `PC2`. I have a Python project `M` that is currently being developed on `PC1`.

I want to copy `M` from `PC1` to `PC2`. The issue is that `PC2` has no internet connection and, as such, cannot use `pip` to install packages. I have already tried copying the `virtualenv` folder from `PC1` to `PC2` to no avail.

Please note that making the program executable (using a tool such as `PyInstaller` is not an option).

Given this information, how can I copy and run `M` from `PC1` to `PC2`?

Comment: Maybe you can create a virtualenv with same name and then replace the folder.

Comment: You can use a tool like Docker: https://www.docker.com/

Comment: Use `pip wheel -r requirements.txt` and copy all the generated wheel files to the other machine. Then run `pip install *.whl`.

Comment: good idea. One problem is that pip is not installed in PC2. Is it save to copy pip?@KlausD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have already tried copying the virtualenv folder from PC1 to PC2 to
>   no avail.

What was the error you got? Did you activate the virtualenv on PC2? Is it on the same directory level as on PC2? For the activation, you can read up here: 
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/

> good idea. One problem is that pip is not installed in PC2. Is it save
>   to copy pip?

PIP is also installed automatically in the venv, it should be located in ENV/bin/pip

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda you could proceed as follows:

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/TJBtuWab1DE

But as mentioned before, that's the intended usage of docker:

https://www.docker.com/